# the button element not responding

Tags: javascript, jquery

please tell me whats wrong with my jquery code (it looks that everything is oky but its still not working !)
the button generate is not working and nothing happen when i click it !

ps : i have searched about this problem everywhere and i can't find the soulition also i treid by myself and same problem

thanks

```js
$('#meta_mal_api_button').click(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();

  var valMALID = $('input[name=meta_mal_api_input]').get(0).value;

  var languange = "<?php echo $langu; ?>";

  var target = document.URL;
  $.getJSON("https://mal.developersidn.com/anime/?id=https://myanimelist.net/anime/" + valMALID + languange, function(json) {
    $.each(json, function(key, val) {

      var valTitle = "";
      if (key == "<?php echo $titleml; ?>") {
        valTitle += "" + val + "";
        $('input[name=dev_title]').val(valTitle);
        $("input[name=post_title]").val(valTitle);
      }

      var valEnglish = "";
      if (key == "english") {
        valEnglish += "" + val + "";
        $("input[name=dev_english]").val(valEnglish);
      }

      var valJapanese = "";
      if (key == "japanese") {
        valJapanese += "" + val + "";
        $("input[name=dev_japanese]").val(valJapanese);
      }

      var valStatus = "";
      if (key == "status") {
        valStatus += "" + val + "";
        $("select[name=dev_status]").val(valStatus);
      }

      var valType = "";
      if (key == "type") {
        valType += "" + val + "";
        $("select[name=dev_type]").val(valType);
      }

      var valDuration = "";
      if (key == "duration") {
        valDuration += "" + val + "";
        $("input[name=dev_duration]").val(valDuration);
      }

      var valDuration = "";
      if (key == "duration") {
        valDuration += "" + val + "";
        $("input[name=dev_duration]").val(valDuration);
      }


      var valProducer = "";
      if (key == "producers") {
        valProducer += "" + val + "";
        $("input#new-tag-producers").val(valProducer);
      }

      <?php if($catmal == '1') { ?>
      var valTitleCat = "";
      if (key == "<?php echo $titleml; ?>") {
        valTitleCat += "" + val + "";
        $('input#newcategory').val(valTitleCat);
        $("input#category-add-submit").click();
      }

      <?php } ?>
      var valScore = "";
      if (key == "score") {
        valScore += "" + val + "";
        $("input[name=dev_score]").val(valScore);
      }

      var valDate = "";
      if (key == "aired") {
        valDate += "" + val + "";
        $("input[name=dev_date]").val(valDate);
      }

      var valDate = "";
      if (key == "aired") {
        valDate += "" + val + "";
        $("input[name=dev_date]").val(valDate);
      }

      var valTrailer = "";
      if (key == "pv") {
        valTrailer += "" + val + "";
        $("input[name=dev_trailer]").val(valTrailer);
      }

      var valRating = "";
      if (key == "score") {
        valRating += "" + val + "";
        $("input[name=dev_rating]").val(valRating);
      }

      var valUsers = "";
      if (key == "users") {
        valUsers += "" + val + "";
        $("input[name=dev_users]").val(valUsers);
      }


      var valSource = "";
      if (key == "source") {
        valSource += "" + val + "";
        $("input[name=dev_source]").val(valSource);
      }


      var valTotalEpisode = "";
      if (key == "episodes") {
        valTotalEpisode += "" + val + "";
        $("input[name=dev_episode]").val(valTotalEpisode);
      }

      var valSeason = "";
      if (key == "premiered") {
        valSeason += "" + val + "";
        $('input#new-tag-season').val(valSeason);
      }

      var valGenre = "";
      if (key == "genres") {
        valGenre += "" + val + "";
        $('input#new-tag-genre').val(valGenre);
      }

      var valStudio = "";
      if (key == "studios") {
        valStudio += "" + val + "";
        $('input#new-tag-studio').val(valStudio);
      }



      var valImg = "";
      var valAutoupload = "1";
      if (key == "image") {
        valImg += "" + val + "";
        // Insert image using ajax
        if (valAutoupload == '<?php echo $autoupload; ?>') {
          var poster = valImg;
          //alert(poster);
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: target,
            data: {
              'poster_url': poster,
            },
            success: function(response) {
              $("input[name=dev_featured]").val(response);
            }
          });
        } else {
          $("input[name=dev_featured]").val(valImg);
        }
      }
      var valDesc = "";
      if (key == "synopsis") {
        var output = val.replace(/\n/g, "<br />");
        valDesc += "" + output + "";
        if (typeof tinyMCE != "undefined") {
          var editor_id = wpActiveEditor;
          if ($('#wp-' + editor_id + '-wrap').hasClass('tmce-active') && tinyMCE.get(editor_id)) {
            tinyMCE.get(editor_id).setContent(valDesc);
          } else {
            $("textarea[name=content]").val(valDesc);
          }
        }
      }

    });
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rwmb-clone rwmb-text-clone">
  <input size="30" type="text" id="meta_mal_api_input" value="28249" class="rwmb-text " name="meta_mal_api_input">
  <a href="#" class="button-primary" id="meta_mal_api_button">Generate</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Any error message from the console?

Comment: Also share the full php page where this script is being executed.

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava errr, please not the *full* PHP, just a [mcve] - Although in this case I am not sure it is needed as the issue seems to be on the JS/front-end side, not the back-end/PHP side

Answer (score 3):

Add your jquery code in document ready block.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

    });
```

The element is not loaded into the DOM when the click function is bound to the element.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using an anchor tag as your button, you should be preventing the default behavior of the link before adding your custom functionality:

```
$('#meta_mal_api_button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ...
});
```

Working sample code:

```js
$('#meta_mal_api_button').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert('Button clicked');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rwmb-clone rwmb-text-clone">
  <input size="30" type="text" id="meta_mal_api_input" value="28249" class="rwmb-text " name="meta_mal_api_input">
  <a href="#" class="button-primary" id="meta_mal_api_button">Generate</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Too add to this - your a should be <a href="#" ….. >

Comment: @anton what errors are you getting? Is the anchor tag hardcoded in the HTML, or is it being generated with JavaScript? Also, be sure to add an `href` to your anchor as @alpharomeo suggested.

Comment: yes i added it and nothing happend (i just send me back to the top ) with no errors
nothing in consol too

Comment: Sending you back to the top is the default behavior of an anchor tag with a `#`, so you do not have the `preventDefault` set up correctly. Did you add `e` into the parenthesis of the `function`?

Comment: Well, it does look correct. The only other thing I can think of is that jQuery is not being loaded correctly. When you click the button, are you getting any errors in the developer console? If so, what errors?

Comment: I'm not sure what else it could be, I've added a code sample based on the code you provided to my answer and as you can see, it is working correctly. Go back and make sure you don't have any typos in your code.

Comment: Check the network tab (or equivalent) to see if jQuery is loaded?